# App mock-up with description using only HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to make a section like the image above with only CSS and only use images for the dotted lines if I have to (unless there's also a way to do this with html/CSS?)

Is absolute positioning the only way to do this? I usually ten to avoid absolute positioning because it is a pain to make responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dotted lines by setting a dotted border on an empty element.

Unfortunately, I don't see any way to make elements overlap without using some sort of positioning.

Comment: And I can angle the lines? It would prob be better to use images than. I just usually have trouble with absolute positioning, so I try to avoid it.

Comment: Yep, you can do rotations and more with CSS transforms.

Comment: Also, responsive design and absolute positioning don't have to be mutually exclusive...
I believe it's common to use absolute positioning inside a container with `position:relative`. You can then squish or move the container however you want, and the absolutely positioned elements move with it.